# How to set USRP antenna in GNU-radio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, uhd

I am new in gnu-radio and USRP.

I have installed uhd and i can find the USRP-device when running `uhd_find_devices`

However, when I just follow the simple tutorial and construct that graph, there is some error I cannot understand.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9auM.jpg)

The error is:

```
RuntimeError: AssertionError: assertion failed:
TX/RX is not a valid xcvr antenna name.
Possible values are: [J1,J2]
```

Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: GNU Radio Companion has a built-in screen capture function. Use that next time instead of a camera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, go into your UHD block, and in "RF settings" select "Antenna" to be "J1" or "J2", instead of "TX/RX".

Also, don't use PSK Mod. It's deprecated. It doesn't work.

Also, the sample rate is too low.

Also, there's no 200 MHz clock rate in a USRP2 or N200 or N210.

Also, your GNU Radio seems to be very old. Maybe update your Linux to a newer version, and then you automatically get a more modern GNU Radio.

Comment: Hi @huimoumou! The way to mark helpful answers here is not by commenting, but by using the upvote button.